# Error Compiling Micronaut Launch Groovy project

Tags: micronaut

I used the Micronaut Launch to create a base project for a CLI application, with Groovy as the language, and including the http-client feature. When I try to compile this generated code, I get the following compile error.

```
Error starting type visitor [io.micronaut.validation.routes.RouteValidationVisitor@6577c0]: io/micronaut/http/server/types/files/StreamedFile
```

Does anyone have any insight into this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your build.gradle dependencies

```
dependencies {
+   annotationProcessor("info.picocli:picocli-codegen")
+   annotationProcessor("io.micronaut:micronaut-http-validation")
    implementation("info.picocli:picocli")
    implementation("io.micronaut:micronaut-http-client")
    implementation("io.micronaut:micronaut-jackson-databind")
    implementation("io.micronaut.groovy:micronaut-runtime-groovy")
    implementation("io.micronaut.picocli:micronaut-picocli")
    implementation("jakarta.annotation:jakarta.annotation-api")
-   compileOnly("info.picocli:picocli-codegen")
-   compileOnly("io.micronaut:micronaut-http-validation")
    runtimeOnly("ch.qos.logback:logback-classic")
    implementation("io.micronaut:micronaut-validation")

}
```

Can you open an issue in [Micronaut Starter](https://github.com/micronaut-projects/micronaut-starter)?
Only seeing the CLI application issue with Groovy.